# Java Socket: NTP application always return null string

Tags: java, sockets, network-protocols

I have use some code to take time from NTP (Network Time Protocol). I have tried many servers from [this list](http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi) but always receive an empty string. I don't know this is because server error, or my code has some problem.

Here is my code:

```
String machine = "utcnist2.colorado.edu";
// standart port on Computer to take time of day on normal computer
final int daytimeport = 13;

Socket socket = null;
try {
    socket = new Socket(machine, daytimeport);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    String time = reader.readLine();
    System.out.printf("%s says it is %s %n", machine, time);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are talking about this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol, right?

Comment: OK, I was confused. This is _not_ NTP. It's a different protocol. But anyway: Are you getting just empty Strings or also exceptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparently, the server returns two lines. Adding `reader.readLine();` just before `String time = reader.readLine();` makes it work.

Full code would be:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String machine = "utcnist2.colorado.edu";
    // standart port on Computer to take time of day on normal computer
    final int daytimeport = 13;

    Socket socket = null;
    try {
        socket = new Socket(machine, daytimeport);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        reader.readLine();
        String time = reader.readLine();
        System.out.printf("%s says it is %s %n", machine, time);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read the lines until the String returned by `reader.readLine();` is null. By then you have reached the end of the stream. This should actually be done in a loop, but the code above is enough for this example.